# RESTful API Design: ID values for "owned" resources

Tags: api, rest

When designing a restful API, resource ownership is a consideration when designing the URIs. In my case, I'm working on an API where two of my entities will be people and addresses. Each person can have more than one address, so in the database they'll be in separate tables.

Normally I just use auto incrementing keys, so each new record adding increases the ID number.

A thought I had was that if I uses this approach, it would effectively produce a URI like this:

`/people/11/addresses/52`

In that case, `person` *11* doesn't have *52* `addresses`. It's just person *11*, who has an address with an ID of *52*.

The other side of it is whether I would even be using a URI like that. Addresses generally won't be retrieved on their own by the client, but as part of a person object retrieved by a single API call (`/people/11` would retrieve all addresses associated with that person).

Anyway, I guess the question here is about best practices. Is it common to see an entity owned by another with ID values like that? What are the general practices with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is correct.
Also These are general rules ([reference](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api)):

```
- An API is a user interface for a developer - so put some effort into making it pleasant
- Use RESTful URLs and actions
- Use SSL everywhere, no exceptions
- An API is only as good as its documentation - so have great documentation
- Version via the URL, not via headers
- Use query parameters for advanced filtering, sorting & searching
- Provide a way to limit which fields are returned from the API
- Return something useful from POST, PATCH & PUT requests
- HATEOAS isn't practical just yet
- Use JSON where possible, XML only if you have to
- You should use camelCase with JSON, but snake_case is 20% easier to read
- Pretty print by default & ensure gzip is supported
- Don't use response envelopes by default
- Consider using JSON for POST, PUT and PATCH request bodies
- Paginate using Link headers
- Provide a way to autoload related resource representations
- Provide a way to override the HTTP method
- Provide useful response headers for rate limiting
- Use token based authentication, transported over OAuth2 where delegation is needed
- Include response headers that facilitate caching
- Define a consumable error payload
- Effectively use HTTP Status codes
```

Also there are lots of references on web.  [This](http://blog.mwaysolutions.com/2014/06/05/10-best-practices-for-better-restful-api/) page is a good start.
and these are also useful: [slide1](http://www.slideshare.net/cesare.pautasso/some-rest-design-patterns-and-antipatterns), [devzone tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/common-rest-design-pattern)

Comment: Thanks, this is awesome. Reading over it made me think of two more questions. 1) what do you mean about pagination in link headers? I was thinking of using request params for that, so how would I do this? 2) REST security/authentication is something I'm looking into right now. I generally just use Spring Security for that, are there any tips you have to using that RESTfully? Specifically on how to maintain statelessness?

Comment: Link header introduced by [EFC 5988](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5988#page-6) and intended to indicating the relationships between resources on the Web:
`Link: <https://api.github.com/user/repos?page=3&per_page=100>; rel="next", <https://api.github.com/user/repos?page=50&per_page=100>; rel="last"`

and token based authentication is a token in your API:
`https://api.test.com/get/some/info?token=12345`
Thats why you always need ssl! to hide the token!

Answer (score 3):

You would normally use a resource like: /people/11/addresses/52 when you return the details of an address in a personalised manner for the people entity.

If for example, you have entities: people and office which can have addresses, and for people you want to display only the country and for offices you want to display all the details of addresses.

On the other hand, if you don't need customization you can also use an url like: /address/12 , since it will be easier to cache a response like that.

> Addresses generally won't be retrieved on their own by the client,
>   but as part of a person object retrieved by a single API call
>   (/people/11 would retrieve all addresses associated with that person).

If this is the case you can leave out the detailed addresses url.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, That's correct way to apply many to many relation in APIs. Just remember to check id2 belongs to id1 when returning the value.

For retrieving all the addresses the correct call is `/people/11/addresses`. Then you know you have to call a join query.